# How long are the nacelle strakes on a GE-90?

Tags: jet-engine, boeing-777

For my school project, I'm doing something where I create a nacelle strake on a model plane and I want to make it to scale. Could you please let me know the dimensions of a nacelle strake? I would greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

You can measure this on photos.

1. Find a nice side view that shows the nacelle strake.
2. Measure the engine diameter on the photo.
3. Find the engine diameter in the engine specifications.
4. Calculate the ratio between the two. This gives you a scale factor of the photo.
5. Measure the strake, multiply by the scale factor to give the size of the strake on the real engine.
6. Divide by the scale factor of your model to get the size of the strake on your model.

I use a spreadsheet so I can do step 2-6 once. I then create a formula that converts a dimension I measured on the photo to the one I need on the model. Makes it easy to do lots of measurements on a photo.
I usually import the photo into an application that uses SI measurement units (Adobe Illustrator), but you can measure in pixels too (which allows you to use cheap image tools).

Comment: I'd add: 7. Find front view that shows the strake 8. Account for the strake's orthographic projection (mounting angle)

Comment: While complex, this sounds like a better option than "go to your nearest airport, wander out to the apron with a tape measure and a ladder". ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an actual response but hints meant to help. Steps suggested by Hobbes are usually how it's done, but I'll dig in more in details.

About finding a photo, it's quite hard because the strake is on the inboard side. Most if not all photos are highly distorded due to perspective and you can't take the shot far enough from the opposite side as the fuselage kicks in. Most photos doesn't display the entirety of the engine, or are not large enough to make precise computation (such as those photos taken below and from the side of the aircraft on final, you can clearly see the strake and the entirety of the engine). By experience, I recommand flickr for such photos. You can get high resolution from authors (usually, a mail explaining your goals will do, but you may wait a week or much more before getting the photos for obvious reasons)

**Alternative 1**

High detailed 3-views from the manufacturer (including the company who designed the strakes). Best views are vector drawings (DXF), but it's not usually free and if you don't have an account to pay online (just like me) that's a no-go. But if you can, don't forget the strake is tilted, the measures  you get from the top view are not the actual size, the strake is slightly larger. Get the angle from the front view and do the appropriate computations. It's worth to note that, any drawing is the numerical hand made or formula-generated copy of the real thing, and there will **always** be some errors.

In the same principle, you may directly contact someone among the finest views drawers out there. One that come to mind is Jennings Heilig. I know he made drawings explaining the differences between the 777 engines (as related in [this DAC post](https://www.diecastaircraftforum.com/1-200-scale-model-aircraft/87848-geminijets-september-release-pictures.html) - I don't have J.R. Heilig contact) Those views builders uses the Alternative 3 below.

**Alternative 2**

Some Aviation SE members do build scale models, but due to the mass variety of questions about aviation, they may not spot this one or they have other things to do right now. The point is, scale model builders usually have detailed drawing of the model, and perhaps even the dimensions of most components of the aircraft. The Boeing 777 has several types of engines and some scale model documents explain the differences. Why not ask on a scale model forum like finescale or DAC ? By narrowing the potential readers to the ones highly caring about scalings and proportions, you may have the answer faster.

Because scale models are commercial products, you can't undisclose drawing informations contained in the build manual. But you can ask for precise information privately.

**Alternative 3** is a mix of all those, extremely time consuming, where you're doing the thing yourself (DIY) and cross check everything. Actually, I started this as I'm 3D modelling the 777 right now, but I'm not yet carring about the strakes. The Boeing Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning is a PDF document. Unfortunately, not only the most detailed views is for the 777-200F, but the strakes are missing from the top views (only there for the front view). And here you have a perfect example of drawing error : Distance from nose tip and engine cowling tip is 84ft 6in for the Boeing 777-300ER in the document. But that's wrong, the Boeing 777-300ER have longer engines (GE90-115B), the distance is for one of the -300 model (not ER) with shorter engine nacelles (I don't know for sure PW, GE or RR). The point is not to blame Boeing, but to explain ***why you should be very carefull not 100% thrusting a drawing even if it comes directly from the manufacturer***. Small errors like that usually happen.

It's worth to note that you should select the appropriate engine from the start. The strakes are probably different for each type of nacelle.

- Boeing 777-200(ER) and 777-300 have 3 types : GE90-9*, PW and RR
- Boeing 777-200(LR), 777-200F and 777-300ER have one type : GE90-11*
- Boeing 777-8X/9X have one type (not in service yet)

Find the photos with the target engine. You can use several websites like [this one](https://www.airfleets.net/home/) to identify which engine is installed on which airframe.

Now, you have the drawings, layer them with appropriate photos taken from far away (those from below and the side). Note that the 777 engines nacelles are nor perfectly circular, and doesn't look like truncated ellipses from the side, but slightly distored. You should take account of the fact that the 13ft diameter is not the diameter of the nacelle, but the distance between the highest point and the lowest, which are a few feet apart in a vertical projection. The nacelle width from a top view is slightly narrower (but most drawing views from top blindly assume 13ft is the max width of the nacelle). It's pure try and narrow error margins.

Use aswell rivets and seams lines from detailed photos to pinpoint the most precise location of the strake.

Further more, the engines are tilted, both in the horizontal plan, and the frontal plan. When measuring the strake (SI units in appropriate tool or pixels in a drawing tool), you should either un-tilt the engine, or do the appropriate computations. What I'll would do is get the most precise projections in the views, draw the strake 3D, and measure the distance between points... but I'm nowhere to get there yet I don't have the time to in the next weeks.

1. Boeing DXF Drawings are [here](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/3_view.page)
2. Boeing Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning are [here](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/plan_manuals.page)

And just a personal opinion : Unless you're doing some sort of airfoil specific experiment/demonstration with an 1:5 or larger scaled model replica, most people won't care about on-scale or not the moment proportions are kept realistic. Keep in mind the size of your model and the materials you'll use to make the replica : are your materials thin and easy to precisely cut enough to respect proportions, while being strong enough to not fall apart upon handling..??